# Spin connection for a vector field

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

Using Birrel & Davies convention, the covariant derivative for a field of arbitrary spin in curved spacetime is given by
$$\nabla_\mu=\partial_\mu+\Omega_\mu,\tag{1}$$
with
$$\Omega_\mu=\frac{1}{2}\Sigma^{\alpha\beta}V_\alpha^\nu(\partial_\mu V_{\beta\nu}-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho V_{\beta\rho}),\tag{2}$$
where $V^\alpha_\mu $ is the $n$-bein and $\Sigma^{\alpha\beta}$ are the generators of the Lorentz group associated with the representation under which the field transforms. Now, for a vector field $A_\nu$, these generators have the following components
$$(\Sigma_{\alpha\beta})^\gamma\,_\delta=\delta^\gamma_\alpha\eta_{\beta\delta}-\delta^\gamma_\beta \eta_{\alpha\delta}\tag{3}.$$
We know that for a vector field
$$\Omega_\mu A_\nu=-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho A_\rho\tag{4},$$
so using $(3)$ we should get
$$(\Omega_\mu)^\rho\,_\nu=-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\rho,$$
but I'm not being able to prove it, I cannot get rid of the $n$-vein in the expression I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with new notation.

I define the covariant derivative as
$$\nabla_\mu=\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{2}\omega^{ab}_\mu\Sigma_{ab},$$
where $\Sigma_{ab}$ are the generators of the Lorentz group associated with the representation under which the field transforms, and $\omega^{ab}_\mu$ the spin connection
$$\omega^{ab}_\mu=e^a_\nu(\partial_\mu e^{b\nu}+\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}e^{b\lambda}).$$

The generators in the vectorial representation have the following components
$${(\Sigma_{ab})^c}_d=\delta^c_a\eta_{bd}-\delta^c_b\eta_{ad},$$
such that
$$\nabla_\mu A^c\equiv{(\nabla_\mu)^c}_d A^d=\partial_\mu A^c+\omega^{\,c}_{\mu\, d} A^d.$$

On the other hand, we know
$$\nabla_\mu A^\nu=\partial_\mu A^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}A^\rho,$$
and also
\begin{align}
  \nabla_\mu A^\nu&=e^\nu_c\nabla_\mu A^c\\
  &=e^\nu_c\partial_\mu A^c+e^\nu_c\omega^{\,c}_{\mu\, d} A^d\\
  &=\partial_\mu A^\nu-A^d\partial e^\nu_d+e^\nu_c e^c_\lambda\Big(\partial_\mu e^\lambda_d+\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\rho}e^\rho_d\Big) A^d\\
  &=\partial_\mu A^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\rho}A^\rho,
\end{align}
so everything works fine.